# Create JPA tables to embedded Derby in Web Sphere 8.5.5

Tags: jpa, openjpa, websphere-8

How do you need to configure JPA-project (EAR) and the Web Sphere Application (8.5.5) server to make the OpenJPA create tables when the EAR is started on the server?

I have created a datasource (name: userregister, JNDI: jdbc/userregister) in WAS using the default settings.

in META-INF/persistence.xml I have the following.

```
<persistence-unit name="urPU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <!-- OpenJPA -->
  <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/userregister</jta-data-source>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
  <properties>
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(foreignKeys=true,schemaAction='dropDB,add')" />
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults" value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict" />
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(foreignKeys=true)" />
    <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE,SQL=TRACE" />
    <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="APP" />
    <!-- <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="APP" /> -->
    <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If I select the persistence.xml by right clicking in eclipse I can generate the class list in the file. Though I am unable to create the classes in the db manually => I assume this should happen at deploy anyway.

The database is created and in the log is jpa entries:

```
The Java Persistence API (JPA) component is initializing.
The com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl class is loaded as the default Java Persistence API (JPA) provider.
The Java Persistence API (JPA) component has initialized.
...
The Java Persistence API (JPA) component is starting.
The Java Persistence API (JPA) component has started.
...
OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
```

Looking at the log output, Should there be some other properties since IBM-specific provider is used when I am actually configuring OpenJPA settings? (Both should be found from WAS by default if I have understood correctly)

Note:
I noticed that if I changed the JNDI name from persistence.xml to something invalid, I had no errors. I was trying to check that the JPA actually connects with the data source.
What should be expected and/or what is possibly wrong?
By the log the JPA seems to get started.

Comment: Found this: "If no JPA provider is configured in the <provider> element of the persistence.xml file within an Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) module, the default JPA provider that is currently configured for this server is used." If I omit the persistence.xml there are no JPA entries in the log, but when present it seems the file is treated as "empty"?

Comment: Select the default JPA provider from a list of providers included with the product.

    Open the administrative console.
    Click Servers > Application Servers
    Select a server.
    Click Container Services > Default Java Persistence API Settings
    Select Select a default persistence provider that is included with WebSphere Application Server.
    Click the slider and select from the list.
    Click Apply and save the configuration.
...
Default provider was changed, but the problem persists.

Comment: The `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>` should be enough. The tables will be created during first request to database. What kind of errors do you see, as there are none in the log you attached.

Answer (score 0):

All problems (probably) may have been caused by bad project settings (ear). When the ear-project containing this JPA was taken in to use as a dependency, it prevented the main project from running properly.
So even that there were log output about JPA recognized properly, it never got so far (actually used the db) so that it could had done anything. Strange thing is that there is never anything in the logs about the real issue and even the project deploys fine (no erros/warnings in log) on WAS, but crashes after login-page (even that none of the JPA-stuff was actually used. All happened just when having the dependency).

I changed the provider to EclipseLink (+ options accordingly) which helped me to create the classes manually via Eclipse. I also modified the project settings (too much to describe here, they were originally copied from another ear-project) which enabled the module to work properly when used as a dependency in the main project.

I may later do some additional tests to see if the OpenJPA would had worked also, but will settle with the EclipseLink for now.

This is not much of an answer since can't pinpoint the exact problem. Plausibly there is/was nothing wrong with the JPA.